# Homology of Torelli subgroup groups of automorphism groups of free products

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gt.geometric-topology, group-cohomology

For a group $G$, let $G^{*n}$ denote the $n$-fold free product. There is a natural map $Aut((\mathbb Z/k\mathbb Z)^{*n}) \mapsto GL_n(\mathbb Z/k\mathbb Z)$. Is it known if the group homology of the kernel of this map is finitely generated in each homological degree? This is false if you replace $\mathbb Z/k\mathbb Z$ with $\mathbb Z$.